# Magento category display problem on homepage on the left and right column

Tags: magento

Hi i have magento store in which i have 4 category which i want to display on my homepage on 2 on left column and 2 on right column so how could that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to check out `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml`. Its the template in which categories are rendered. You can limit the number of categories by a simple `if` inside the `foreach ($_categories as $_category)` block (`if($i++<2)` for instance). Then, go to the template of your second column (wherever you got it in your layout) and insert a similar code (whit a `if($i++>2` or something more sophisticated) in it. Not the cleanest way, but I think that its one of the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Find the category ID from the backend and display the products as you require. You can use the same file as M_F has suggested.